# Can I extract the full command line from an atop 1.23 data file?

Tags: atop

My production servers have [`atop`](http://www.atoptool.nl/) version 1.23, and I have a data file written by it from which I need to extract the full command line of a process.

Unfortunately:

- this version of `atop` won't display data beyond the 80th column of the display
- horizontal scrolling was only introduced in 1.27
- newer versions refuse to read data files written by older versions
- the file itself is compressed, so a simple `strings` search won't work

Is there any way I can recover the full command line from my data file?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying that `atop` itself will truncate at the 80th column. Therefore the "full" command line is not in the data file, only the first 80 characters. How can you recover something that is not there? Is using `ps` or `top -c` instead of atop an option?

Comment: I suspect the command line may be in the data file but is not being displayed by `atop`.  I need the data from the file because I'm looking at a specific event in the past.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**. After checking the man page, looks like you can get the full command line with:

```
atop -r /var/log/atop.log -P PRG
```

Some general approach to extract data from compressed files:

I can extract data from the atop log files with:

```
xxd -p < /var/log/atop.log |
  fold -w4 |
  awk -v cmd='xxd -r -p | zlib-flate -uncompress | strings' '
    /789c/{if (x) close(cmd); x=1}; x {print | cmd}' |
  grep your-command
```

The idea being to detect the zlib header (starting with `789c`) and pass that to `zlib-flate -uncompress`. Not guaranteed bulletproof and not the most efficient way to do it, but does the trick for me.

Alternatives to `zlip-flate -uncompress` (part of [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net)) include `openssl zlib -d` and `pigz -zd`.

Comment: Impressive stuff sir!  Unfortunately it seems that `atop` 1.23 does indeed truncate in the data file at 80 characters.  Many thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 5):

In a newer version there is an interactive command - `c` that shows the command line of the process with their arguments.

To do this you would find the location of your atop logs (eg. `/var/log/atop/atop_20191209`) and supply that to atop using the `-r` switch like so: `atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20191209` then press <kbd>t</kbd> to advance the time. To rewind the time you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Comment: Does that work when reading from a file?

Comment: And is that usable  when reading from a file ***that was written by an earlier version**?*

Comment: I can confirm that it works when reading from a file @JeffSchaller. Not sure about if it is from an earlier version though.

Comment: @Kredns: happy to hear! If you're able, suggest an edit to the post that shows how to do it; that would make the Answer even more valuable. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller, good idea, done! :)

Comment: @Kredns -- did we lose the `c` portion of the answer to corresponds to showing the command-line? (That's the point of this overall question)

Comment: @JeffSchallerI did not remove anything from the answer, only added how to view the logs.